# How does hearing range work?

Tags: league-of-legends

In some situations in League of Legends, you can hear things that you can't see. For example, I'm pretty sure you can hear some enemy skill uses in a nearby bush.

I haven't been able to find any documentation about this mechanic, and am wondering how it works. For example, knowing the following might be useful:

- Assuming I don't have sight to the blue buff, if I'm on the "outside" of the wall around the golem camp, should I be able to hear an enemy working on taking the golem down? (Same thing for wraiths.)
- Can I hear skills used from a bush? (Which ones?)

Assuming I can hear things that I can't see: what is the range of hearing?

Comment: I know that the position of your camera affects lots of sounds.  For example, attack noises, jokes, and taunts sound different depending on what is on screen at the moment.  Try wearing headphones, saying your joke, and moving the camera around to observe this effect.  Unfortunately I have no idea if skills work the same way.

Comment: Good point -- I was aware of the joke/taunt sounds fading with camera distance in the back of my mind, but didn't connect it to this question in my head.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips - having currently issues with a bad cable making my right speaker go off occasionally, I can confirm that sound in general is linked to the camera position. Now for more details on hidden sounds, I don't know precisely. I would assume you hear when you can actually see. Like a "puf" of smoke from Shaco, or Nunu's ultimate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I am not sure if I can fully answer this question, but I'll try since noone else seems to be able to say something about this. I tried this stuff in custom games, so I am pretty sure this is correct:

1. There is no "hearing range". Obviously you do hear some actions, but everything you hear is limited to your camera vision, which obviously means you have to have vision over the area and you have to watch it if you want to hear anything.
2. You should not be able to hear the abilities used around the corner or over a wall (like in the scenario you described at blue buff), but sometimes, you are able to see some abilites to the fog of war (just like Shaco's Decieve), but most of these vision are bugs. Examples for such abilities are Malphites Ground Slam, Maokais Arcane Smash or Lee Sins Sonic Wave. Since these abilities are only visible due to bugs, you can't or at least you shouldn't really count on beeing able to see them.
3. You cannot hear skills used from bushes unless its warded or you have vision through other skills/spells, but if an ability goes out of a bush (like Leonas E or Nidalees Spear) and you're watching that bush, you can hear the spell as soon as he leaves the bush, even if you dont have vision in the bush itself, or if the spell misses.

So I'd say seeing = hearing. If you are able to catch an area (Thats not in fog of war) with your camera, you can hear everything you have vision off.

Something important to note: If you use a skill into a bush or an area you have no vision of (Fog of War), and this skill makes a certain sound if it hits something, you will hear that sound if you hit someone, even tho you have no vision over the target itself. Premise for this is obv you "watching" the area.

Comment: What about sounds from your abilities? If I cleaver into a bush and it hits something that makes a sound. But what if I cleaver over a wall and it hits something in fog of war, can I hear that?

Comment: yes you can, if your cam is covering the area obv. Kennens Shuriken over a wall makes a sound as well, or Urgots Q

Comment: If an ability makes a confirmation sound upon connecting with an enemy, it will still go off (e.g. Mundos' Cleaver, Olafs' Axe, Morgana's Q, etc.)

Comment: If you can demonstrate your results with some screenshots, then the bounty's yours. For example, for different situations, show pairs of screenshots: 1) [pic] you can hear this & 2) [pic] you can't hear this.

Comment: Guess you mean me?^^ I have a replay but to cut your parts out will take some time (tested several diffrent things). I'll see if I can do it tommorrow, I'm from europe and its 01 a.m. right now